# any one can help me with this, i want to make a dynamic route from starting point to end point, while avoiding other svg

Tags: javascript, jquery

`anyone can help me creating a dynamic route in this floor plan. i have a problem on routing which is its creating a straight path only.
var dom = document.getElementById("floorplan-container");
var myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {
renderer: "canvas",
useDirtyRect: false,
});
var app = {};
var ROOT_PATH = "";
var option;

```
  $.get(ROOT_PATH + "floorplan.svg", function (svg) {
    echarts.registerMap("floorplan", { svg: svg });


    option = {
      title: {
        text: "Visit Route",
        left: "center",
        bottom: 10,
      },
      tooltip: {},
      geo: {
        map: "floorplan",
        roam: true,
        emphasis: {
          itemStyle: {
            color: undefined,
          },
          label: {
            show: false,
          },
        },
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "Route",
          type: "lines",
          coordinateSystem: "geo",
          geoIndex: 0,
          emphasis: {
            label: {
              show: false,
            },
          },
          polyline: true,
          lineStyle: {
            color: "#c46e54",
            width: 5,
            opacity: 1,
            type: "dotted",
          },
          effect: {
            show: true,
            period: 8,
            color: "#a10000",
            constantSpeed: 80,
            trailLength: 0,
            symbolSize: [20, 12],
            symbol:
              "path://M35.5 40.5c0-22.16 17.84-40 40-40s40 17.84 40 40c0 1.6939-.1042 3.3626-.3067 5H35.8067c-.2025-1.6374-.3067-3.3061-.3067-5zm90.9621-2.6663c-.62-1.4856-.9621-3.1182-.9621-4.8337 0-6.925 5.575-12.5 12.5-12.5s12.5 5.575 12.5 12.5a12.685 12.685 0 0 1-.1529 1.9691l.9537.5506-15.6454 27.0986-.1554-.0897V65.5h-28.7285c-7.318 9.1548-18.587 15-31.2715 15s-23.9535-5.8452-31.2715-15H15.5v-2.8059l-.0937.0437-8.8727-19.0274C2.912 41.5258.5 37.5549.5 33c0-6.925 5.575-12.5 12.5-12.5S25.5 26.075 25.5 33c0 .9035-.0949 1.784-.2753 2.6321L29.8262 45.5h92.2098z",
          },
          data: [
            {`your text`
              // Use label text as coordinates
              coords: [
                [50 * 2, 50 * 2], // Start position
                [350, 50 * 2], // Intermediate position
                // Add more rooms as needed
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    };
    myChart.setOption(option);  
  });

  if (option && typeof option === "object") {
    myChart.setOption(option);
  }

  window.addEventListener("resize", myChart.resize);
</script>`
```